# SQL Server date - 1, first of month issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a stored procedure to do a day - 1, but on the 1st of the month, the reports are blank and I need it to show the last day of the previous month as it works properly every other day. I am assuming because 1-1 = 0. Is there a better logic for this?

I am currently using.

```
WHERE DAY([Audit Control Date]) = (DAY(GETDATE()) - 1)
```

and my date function is below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_Date]
    (@date CHAR(7))
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
    RETURN
        (SELECT ConvertedDate = 
                     CASE WHEN (@date) = 999999 THEN NULL
                          WHEN (@date) = 0 THEN NULL
                          WHEN LEN(@date) = 6 THEN NULL
                          WHEN LEN(@date) = 7 THEN CAST('20' + RIGHT(@date, 6) AS DATE) 
                          ELSE CAST('19' + RIGHT(@date, 6) AS DATE) 
                      END)
END
```

My apologies if this is a stupid question, it just has me stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare date values instead of the day number
`[Audit Control Date] = DATEADD (day , -1 , GetDate() )`

See [DATEADD Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)